# Qt - run function on other thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qapplication

In my simple QApplication I have this scenario:

**Class1** called from main thread.

**Class2** called from other thread that contains a reference of Class1.

Is possible call Class1 function from Class2 using main thread?

I have tried with moveToThread without success. Thanks in advice, best regards.

Daniele

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. I think there is some confusion of terms, e.g. a `class` is a type and as such cannot be called. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Comment: I think you probably want to use signals and slots if i understand your question.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can call a non-static member function of Class1 from Class2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to make the call through a signal to slot connection betweeen the to objects. Specify `Qt::QueuedConnection` or `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` as the connection type when making the connection. This type of connection will queue the signal on the thread of the receiving object.

For details see [ConnectionType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)
and [connect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect)

Comment: Perfect, I used Qt::QueuedConnection and the function is always called on main thread. Thanks